# Running Parameterized Stored Proc From Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, sql-server, sql, power-query

I have been following the tutorial [HERE](http://biinsight.com/power-query-and-sql-server-stored-procedures/) but anytime I try to refresh the workbook, it gives me an error of:

> DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: This database function doesn't support the query option 'Query' with value 'null'.

This is the SQL behind the query, and nothing is returning null, and the stored proc is set-up to accept 3 input parameters.

```
CSR=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="param"]}[Content]{0}[#"CSR"],
d1=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="param"]}[Content]{0}[#"d1"],
d2=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="param"]}[Content]{0}[#"d2"],
Source = Sql.Database("ServerInstanceName", "Credentials", 
[Query="exec [dbo].[StoredProcToRun] '" & Number.ToText(d1)
& "''," & Number.ToText(d2) & "','" & CSR & "'"])
```

And this is the set-up of my stored procedure showing it accepts 3 params:

```
Alter PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcToRun 
@d1 varchar(50), @d2 varchar(50), @CSR varchar(500)

AS
BEGIN
```

What do I need to modify in order for this power query to pass the Excel Parameters to my SQL stored procedure and return the data back to the Excel workbook?

I altered my power query sql to the below and now I get an error of

> Token comma expected

```
[Query="exec [dbo].[StoredProcToRun] 
& Number.ToText(d1) & "','"
& Number.ToText(d2) & "','" 
& CSR & "'"])
```

Comment: one or more Parameter has a null value. Shouldn't be the part "& CSR" not be like the other two Parameters "& Number.ToText(CSR)".

Comment: @visu-l - the CSR value is a text value not a number value.

Comment: since you build a string "exec...." the conversion of this numeric value to a string should be necessary in order to concatenate your substrings. 
On SQL Server you get an error as well if you try "select 'exec [dbo].[StoredProcToRun] ' + 3" instead of "select 'exec [dbo].[StoredProcToRun] ' + CONVERT(varchar, 3 )"

Comment: @visu-l - how would I alter my power query string to convert(varchar,csr)?

Answer (score 0):

make sure to have a string when concatenating your substrings. 
Values, which are numeric (e.g. CSR) have to be converted to a string for the concatenation.

```
CSR=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="param"]}[Content]{0}[#"CSR"],
d1=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="param"]}[Content]{0}[#"d1"],
d2=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="param"]}[Content]{0}[#"d2"],
Source = Sql.Database("ServerInstanceName", "Credentials", 
    [Query="exec [dbo].[StoredProcToRun] '" &
    Number.ToText(d1)  & "','" & 
    Number.ToText(d2)  & "','" & 
    Number.ToText(CSR) & "'"])
```

see also [here](https://reevessmith.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/power-query-and-stored-procedures-with-parameters/) an another example as the tutorial you found.

Just tried with a part of the script to generate the string for the EXEC Statement.
Eventually try to generate the string and copy it on Management Studio to check if it works there.

[image]

Comment: If I add Number.ToText(CSR) I then get an error of unable to convert value "Name Name" to type number.

Comment: which data type recognizes Power Query when loading just the CSR value? This could be the issue. Try eventually Text.From(CSR) instead of Number.ToText.

Comment: Altering to text.from(CSR) gives me an error of DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Procedure or function 'StoredProcToRun' expects parameter '@CSR', which was not supplied.  However, if you look at syntax, it is supplied?!?!?!

Comment: Try on the parameter table to define each column in the table as text before importing in Power Query.
As your tutorial notice: "...To make out life easier I changed the format cell of the “Check Date” column to Text, other wise we’ll need to convert it in Power Query.... "

Comment: I already have them formatted as text, but still get the error of the parameter is not supplied.

Comment: Perhaps the syntax mistake I've just fixed   "& Number.ToText(d1)
& "'',"  instead & Number.ToText(d1)
& "','"

Comment: See my edit.  Still getting an error

Comment: Above you wrote `text.from(CSR)`.  Note that Power Query function names are case-sensitive so you will get an error until you write: `Text.From(CSR)`. HTH